# MacBook Pro A1706 BridgeOS and external EFI

Tags: macos, mac, ssd, macbook-pro

I have recently acquired a MacBook Pro with dead SSD, which seems irreparable. I cannot find the fault on the board. I am running Mojave off an external SSD which gives me no Touch Bar, KB backlight, Camera or Fingerprint sensor. Other than that, everything works just fine. From what I have read these all need bridgeOS to run. I have done all the fiddling I can and have read everything I can about it but no luck. Has anyone had any luck in tricking the embeddedOS to install to an external EFI? When trying to install it gives an error that there is no internal system EFI found.

Comment: A silly quesion, perhaps, but can't you take your external SSD out of its enclosure and install it on your Mac? I once substituted an SSD for a regular HDD, both with OS X already installed, and it worked, but that was OS X...

Comment: I wish it was that easy. This perticular model has everything embedded on the mainboard.

Comment: Ah... I knew there was a catch, what with this being Apri Fool's Day and all... You can turn the candid camera off, I've already made of fool of myself! :-D Back on track: your mentioning bridgeOS reminded me of something I heard the Mac guys at work discuss one day, so I looked it up just now, and found this article (https://mrmacintosh.com/how-to-restore-bridgeos-on-a-t2-mac-how-to-put-a-mac-into-dfu-mode/) that describes how to put a Mac in DFU mode like you would an iPhone. It's more or less the equivalent of the old Target Mode, with a few caveats, and you need a second Mac... 1/2

Comment: 2/2 but it can help restore bridgeOS on the "broken" Mac, since it's on a separate chip, and that's provided the chip itself isn't fried. That would give you a composite Mac, with the OS on the external drive and bridgeOS, hence TouchBar et al, functioning on the Mac itself. Sounds Frankenstein, said like that, but it could work. Or not. Fingers crossed, mate...

Comment: Haha. there is always a catch. There is that option to try too yeah, the trick is finding someone to let me try that with their Mac. I appear to be the only Mac user in a 50km radius. I have a 2011 MacBook Pro which unfortunately doesn't work with that.

Comment: Have you tried this (https://dfarq.homeip.net/fix-dead-ssd/)? Talk about desperate measures...

Answer (score 1):

After many many hours of eyeballing and probing I was able to re-allocate power to the onboard SSD.

By some miracle I was able to fix it!

Win!
[image: Power Fix]